# Flutter/Dart-How to display moths using the Duration package

Tags: flutter, dart, time, duration

Assuming I have a specific no.of seconds as the input and I use the flutter duration package.

```
printDuration(aSecond * 4466000);
```

then the output will be

```
7 weeks 2 days 16 hours 33 minutes 20 seconds
```

what I want is for the output to include months like

```
 1 month 3 weeks 2 days 16 hours 33 minutes 20 seconds
```

is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: The problem is that month is not a fixed size and a duration is a concept of duration of time without any information about when this duration is happening in specific time. So it is impossible to convert a duration to months without making some custom solution where you have a specific date in mind where you are starting from. Or you can make your own solution which just assume that a month is e.g. 30 days.

Answer (score -2):

1. Get second: `duration.inSeconds`
2. Convert to milliseconds
3. Use `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch)`